# Защита от частого обновления страницы, как ВКонтакте.

Tags: php

Доброго времени суток. Интересует такой вопрос. Как можно реализовать подобную защиту у себя на самописном сайте? Что лучше использовать для хранения времени MySQL или сессии? Возможно кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобной задачей? Надеюсь на вашу помощь. Заранее благодарю за ответы и советы.

Comment: Мне кажется лучше под это использовать куки. Пусть все лежит на пользователе.

Comment: Скажите, с какой целью вы хотите ввести подобную защиту? Если с целью защиты от нагрузок, то данную задачу необходимо решать как минимум на уровне fontend'а.

Comment: Да. Для защиты от нагрузок. Не могли бы вы по подробнее описать, что вы имели в виду? Может у вас есть тоже какие-нибудь предложения?

Comment: С куками не вариант, они могут бить отключени.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

nginx, который хорошо ставить фронтендом, и который используют упомянутый ВКонтакте, имеет стандартный модуль [HttpLimitReq](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLimitReqModule), позволяющий ограничить частоту подулючений с одного адреса.

Comment: Спасибо. Попробую.

Answer (score 1):

Устанавливаешь куку с временем текущим если ее раньше не было. Алгоритм такой:

```
if(нету куки['time'])
    установить куку('time', 'время в настоящий момент')

if(кука['time'] < настоящее время - 2 сек. )
    показать "Сильно часто обновляешь товарищ :)"
```

Comment: Благодарю за совет. 
У меня получился вот такой код, но он не правильно работает, не подскажите, в чем проблема?
<code>
<pre class="prettyprint">
<code>
<?php
$time = time();
if(!isset($_COOKIE['time'])) {
 if (SetCookie("time",$time,time()+3600)) 
 {
  echo "<h3>Cookie успешно установлен!</h3>";} else 
  {
   echo "<h3>Cookie установить не удалось!</h3>";
  }
 }
 if ($_COOKIE['time'] < (time() - 2) ) {
 echo "Сильно часто обновляешь товарищ :)";
 }
?>

</code>
</pre>

Comment: У меня получился вот такой код, но он не правильно работает, не подскажите, в чем проблема?
<pre class="prettyprint">
<code>
<?php
$time = time();
if(!isset($_COOKIE['time'])) {
 if (SetCookie("time",$time,time()+3600)) 
 {
  echo "<h3>Cookie успешно установлен!</h3>";} else 
  {
   echo "<h3>Cookie установить не удалось!</h3>";
  }
 }
 if ($_COOKIE['time'] < (time() - 2) ) {
 echo "Сильно часто обновляешь товарищ :)";
 }
?>

</code>
</pre>

Comment: А вы посмотрите что возвращает ф-я time(), нужно сначала перевести время в нормальный формат вот например 

    date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

Ну а далее уже удобнее и понятнее как сравнить 2 даты.

Comment: А потому что ты 1 раз только ставишь куку а ее нужно обновлять постоянно. или как вариант ставить куку с продолжительностью жизни 2 секунды а потом проверять если есть значит часто обновляет если куки нет то все ок и писать новую куку.

Comment: а если я куки отключу?

Comment: @Astarp а я в это время натравлю на ваш сайт робота, который будет парсить его контент. Робот этот, разумеется, никакие куки сохранять не станет, а сервер ваш нагрузит изрядно.
Подумайте ещё раз о серверном решении.

Comment: а если php-сессии, а не куки?

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($_SESSION['time'] + 2 > time()) exit('Хорош там ок да?');
$_SESSION['time'] = time();
```

Еще вот такой пример есть из жизни, в котором ограничивается частота запросов к бд:

```
if ($_SESSION['user']->last_time + 60 < time()) {
    $user = R::findOne('users', "`id` = ?", array($_SESSION['user']->id));
    $user->last_time = time();
    R::store($user);
    $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
}
```

У меня тут хранится сессия юзера с кучей динамических параметров. И не чаще чем раз в минуту я обновляю ее.